# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@Password'.'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wpf

I'm trying to create a login field using (ASP.NET) which will take input from the textbox fields and check them against the "Register" table in my database. The columns are Username and Password. But I am getting an:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Password'.'

error

```
if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
{

    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserLoginAccess", sqlCon); 
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "BEGIN SELECT Username, Password FROM Register WHERE username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", LoginUsername.Text);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", LoginPassword.Password);
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
    int a = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (a == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully");
        MainWindow RegisterSuccessBack = new MainWindow();
        RegisterSuccessBack.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the sqlCmd.CommandText begin with BEGIN?

Comment: That’s a _**very non-secure / “bad practice”**_ method of handling passwords.. especially as, despite good practice guidelines, many passwords are reused, which could lead to additional accounts being compromised.

Comment: And [can we stop using AddWithValue already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: You need to remove "BEGIN" from your SQL query